# Нужно ли делать locker'ы для событий C#?

Tags: .net, c#

Если да, то как?

Comment: Почитайте тут: msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: @vbvbvb, одной ссылки не достаточно для содержательного ответа.

Comment: предлагаете заниматься копипастом? :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нет, не нужно.

Но! Если обработчик события использует какие-то общие для поток объекты, или например GUI контролы, то вот именно их и нужно лочить(в случае контролов, нужно вызывать метод `Invoke()`).

Например есть событие:

```
    public delegate void dMessage(string text); //делегат
    public event dMessage Event1;
```

Тогда обработчик будет выглядеть так:

```
    private void AddTextToLog(string text)
    {
        text += "\r\n";
        if (tbLog.InvokeRequired) //проверяем, нужно ли вызывать Invoke()
            tbLog.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { tbLog.AppendText(text); }));
        else
            tbLog.AppendText(text);
    }
```

Comment: То, что у Вас тут написано - никакая не блокировка. Это прокидывание кода между потоками через интерфейс ISynchronizeInvoke

Answer (score 7):

Событие состоит из поля-делегата и пары методов для того чтобы подписываться и отписываться. Эти методы можно не писать - в этом случае компилятор сам их сгенерирует, и они при вызове будут автоматически блокировать ссылку на текущий объект (или на текущий тип, если событие статическое).

Но конструкция вида `if (this.Event1 != null) this.Event1(this, EventArgs.Empty);` не является потокобезопасной, так как между проверкой и обращением к делегату единственный обработчик в другом потоке может отписаться. Для предотвращения этого рекомендуется взять эту конструкцию в `lock(this)`.

Но в реальности я не сталкивался с тем, чтобы в такой блокировке была необходимость.